# removeView causes all views to disappear

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

In the following code i'm adding TextView into alertDialog and remove them (controlled by two buttons). Adding works fine but remove deletes all the previously added TextView's. Why does it happen and not just the most recent TextView is deleted?

```
final int DIALOG_ADD = 1;
final int DIALOG_REMOVE = 2;

LinearLayout view;
ArrayList<TextView> textViews;

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    adb.setTitle("Custom dialog");

    view = (LinearLayout)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);

    adb.setView(view);
    return adb.create();

}

@Override
protected void onPrepareDialog(int id, Dialog dialog) {

    super.onPrepareDialog(id, dialog);

    switch (id) {

    case DIALOG_ADD:
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText("TextView " + textViews.size());
        view.addView(tv,new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        textViews.add(tv);

        break;

    case DIALOG_REMOVE:

        TextView tv1 = textViews.get(textViews.size() - 1);
        view.removeView(tv1);
        textViews.remove(tv1);

        break;

    };

    TextView tvCount = (TextView)dialog.getWindow().findViewById(R.id.tvCount);
    tvCount.setText("Text view count: " + textViews.size());

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
view.removeViewAt(textViews.size() - 1);
```

instead of

```
view.removeView(tv1);
```